# Python - gray scale formula with PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I want to make greyscale image by my own code.

```
from PIL import Image

path = "people.jpg"

img = Image.open(path)
img = img.convert("LA")
img.save("new_image.png")
```

So I change `img.convert()` for my own formula. But it does not work.

```
from PIL import Image

path = "people.jpg"

img = Image.open(path)
rgb = img.convert("RGB")
width,height = rgb.size

for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        red,green,blue = rgb.getpixel((x,y))
        value = red * 299/1000 + green * 587/1000 + blue * 114/1000
        value = int(value)
        rgb.putpixel((x,y),value)


rgb.save("new.png")
```

Any idea what is wrong? The new image is with red backgroud.

Comment: You're updating an RGB image, so need to use something like `rgb.putpixel((x,y),(value, value, value))`.

Comment: Off topic a little, but the first code snippet creates a greyscale image with alpha, and the second creates an RGB image without any alpha. Aside from your main problem, what exactly do you want, alpha-wise, to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) mentioned, `rgb` is initialized as an RGB (tri-band) image, so it is expecting RGB values. You want grayscale, which only requires a single band. You have two options here:

1. Follow martineau's advice and simply swap out `rgb.putpixel((x,y),value)` for `rgb.putpixel((x, y), (value, value, value))`. This will give it the proper three color values.
2. Create a new grayscale image using `Image.new('L',...)` before putting the pixels into it.

Here's how you might implement option 2 (note that I'm using Python 2.7):

```
from PIL import Image

path = "people.jpg"

img = Image.open(path)
width, height = rgb.size
gray = Image.new('L', (width, height))

for x in xrange(width):
    for y in xrange(height):
        r, g, b = img.getpixel((x, y))
        value = r * 299.0/1000 + g * 587.0/1000 + b * 114.0/1000
        value = int(value)
        gray.putpixel((x, y), value)

gray.save("new.png")
```

Also, if speed is a concern, consider using `putdata()` instead of `putpixel()`. (That's beside the point, so I won't belabor it.)

Comment: +1: Pretty much what I would have suggested if I didn't have to run off and do something else (so didn't have time to write a proper answer as you have done).

Answer (score 0):

Greyscale image will be having a tuple of two values for each pixel - (luminosity value, 255). Creating a new greyscale image and putting values to each pixel will work.

```
greyim=Image.new("LA",(width,height))

for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        red,green,blue = rgb.getpixel((x,y))
        value = red * 299/1000 + green * 587/1000 + blue * 114/1000
        greyim.putpixel((x,y),(value,255))
```

Comment: You're creating a greyscale image with an alpha (transparency) channel here, mode 'LA'. You don't seem to use any transparency at all, so maybe a simple greyscale image (mode 'L') would work too. You'd call putpixel((x,y), value), then.